# React Native React Navigator getPrevState after goBack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I don't understand how  to get the prev state, after I route between screens. Example:

```
index: 3
0: LoginScreen -> route
1: Profile {userId: 1} -> route
2: Profile {userId: 2} -> route
3: Profile {userId: 3} -> goBack.
```

After I dispatch action goBack, screen Profile updates and I have route state

```
index: 2
0: LoginScreen -> route
1: Profile {userId: 1} -> route
2: Profile {userId: 2} -> route
```

But Profile does not get prev props userId=2. Also, the lifecycle methods `componentWillReceiveProps` and `ComponentWillMount` don't get called. How can I route within the same screen, but with different props? Thanks for answering.

Comment: where does `userId` come from? navigation params? state variable?

Comment: yes, navigation params.

Comment: do you mean that you want to `goBack` but with different navigation params?

Comment: Yes. After I goBack, screen get prev props and send ajax for get new data. Now data does't change and It's my problem.